# Why query to find the 3rd highest salary is not working?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee table having salary column.

Now I can find maximum salary by.

```
select max(salary) from emp;
```

And 2nd highest salary by

```
select max(salary) from emp where salary not in (select max(salary)from emp);
```

Now I am trying to find 3rd highest salary using this two..

```
select max(salary) from emp where salary not in 
(
select max(salary)from emp,
select max(salary) from emp where salary not in (select max(salary)from emp)
);
```

Here I am getting error.

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name :
```

Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

WHERE ( n )  here pass which you want 2nd highest or third highest pass as WHERE ( 2 ) for second highest and WHERE (3) for third highest.

```
SELECT *
FROM emp  Emp1
WHERE ( n ) = (
               SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ( Emp2.salary ) )
               FROM emp  Emp2
               WHERE Emp2.salary >= Emp1.salary
            )
```

you can use this also

```
Select TOP 1 salary as '3rd Highest Salary'
from (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 salary from emp ORDER BY salary DESC)
a ORDER BY salary ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simpler method:

```
select *
From(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) 
AS MaxSal,salary from emp
)x where MaxSal=2
```

See example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9451/10).

Now you just have to replace 2 with n to find the nth highest Maximum Salary.

Comment: Edited my answer. See the result in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i would use dense_rank for, this also could give the same salaries, the same "rank".

select
  *
from
 (SELECT 
    SALARY,
    dense_rank () over (order by SALARY desc) as RANK
  from
    EMP)
where
  RANK = 3

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM( 
     SELECT s.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sal DESC) rownumber
     FROM   emp s
     )
WHERE rownumber = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  Select * from 
  (       select e.*, row_number() 
          OVER ( ORDER BY salary DESC ) 
          MaxSal from emp e) 
  MaxSal=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's objecting to the `SELECT` at the beginning of the line:
`SELECT MAX(salary) FROM emp WHERE salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(salary)FROM emp)`
The `IN` list can contain a list of values or a query which returns a list of values, not a list queries. When it saw this `SELECT` it was parsing the previous `FROM` clause an though you where giving it a coma separated list of tables, hence the TABLE NAME error.

To run the query your way you could have written:

`WITH
  EMP AS
    ( SELECT 30000 SALARY FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 30000 SALARY FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 20000 SALARY FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 10000 SALARY FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM emp WHERE salary NOT IN 
(
SELECT MAX(salary)FROM emp
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM emp WHERE salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(salary)FROM emp)
);`

However @Tom's answer gives a nice standard solution with the same result as you. I'd like to offer the following alternative (but use @Tom's):

`SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM emp
ORDER BY salary DESC
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`